# Runge-kutta fourth order for 3 coupled second order equations.

Tags: numerical-methods, stability-in-odes, runge-kutta-methods, nonlinear-dynamics

Someone, please help me by checking whether the steps of the application of RK4 in my calculation is correct or not. I could not find any paper/books/write with similar problems or examples. Calculations for $x_1$, $\dot x_1$, $y_1$, $\dot y_1$,$\ z_1$, $\dot z_1$ is given below with initial conditions : At, $t_0 =0 sec,  r_0 = 3.5 * 10^8 km,  \dot r_0 =x_0=0, $$\theta_0 =(π/2)°$,$\dot \theta_0 =y_0 = 0,  \phi_0=0^∘,  $$\dot \phi_0 = z_0 =0 $,

if, \begin{align} \dot r= x,\, \ddot r = \dot x,\,
\dot \theta&=y,\ddot \theta =\dot y,\,
\dot \phi =z,\,
\ddot \phi=\dot z 
\end{align}
then, the six first-order differential equations:
\begin{alignat}1
\dot r& = x &= f_1(t,r, \theta,\phi,x,y,z)
\\
\dot x &= r[y^2 +(z +Ω)^2(\sin\theta)^2 - \beta z\sin\theta B_\theta)] &= f_2(t,r,\theta,\phi,x,y,z)
\\
\dot \theta &= y &= f_3(t,r,\theta, \phi, x,y,z)
\\
\dot y &= \frac{1}{r}[- 2xy - r(z+ Ω)^2 \sin\theta \cos\theta + \beta r z \sin\theta B_r] &=f_4
 \\
\dot \theta &=z &= f_5(t,r,\theta,\phi,x,y,z)
\\
\dot z &= \frac{1}{r \sin\theta}[-2x(z+Ω)\sin\theta - 2ry(z+ Ω)\cos\theta + \beta(xB_\theta - ryB_r)]&= f_6
\end{alignat}
The solutions are:
\begin{align}
\ x_1   &=\ x_0 + \frac{1}{6} (k_0 + 2k_1 + 2k_2+ k_3)
 \\
\dot x_1 &= \dot x_0 + \frac{1}{6} (l_0 + 2l_1 + 2l_2+ l_3)
\\
y_1      &= y_0 + \frac{1}{6} (m_0 + 2m_1 + 2m_2+ m_3)
\\
\dot y_1 &= \dot y_0 + \frac{1}{6} (n_0 + 2n_1 + 2n_2+ n_3)
\\
z_1      &= z_0 + \frac{1}{6} (p_0 + 2p_1 + 2p_2+ p_3)
\\
\dot z_1 &= \dot z_0 + \frac{1}{6} (q_0 + 2q_1 + 2q_2+ q_3)
\end{align}
To find x_1, we can find $${k_0 = h* f_1(t_0,x_0,y_0,z_0,r_0,\theta_0, \phi_0)}$$ etc.
But to find x_2, what would be the values of $${r_1,\theta_1,\phi_1\quad in\quad f_1(t_1,x_1,y_1,z_!,r_1,\theta_1, \phi_1)} $$ ?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VVzkxPaIX7m6zQ5bP8hZVtImPZwz6XA-/view?usp=sharing

[Soving 3 coupled second order equations using RK4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VVzkxPaIX7m6zQ5bP8hZVtImPZwz6XA-/view?usp=sharing)

[calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06pqB.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2V8B.png)

Comment: This will be much easier to read when it is properly formatted. Start here to find out how: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: RK = Runge-Kutta. Please say it.

Comment: Use `$\dot x$` or `$\ddot x$` for $\dot x$ or $\ddot x$ resp.

Comment: I just edited your last group of formulas in order you have a model.

Comment: @DavidK,@Jean Marie. Thank you for the help. I was not able to put equation no in the same line with the equation so I have removed the numbering.

Comment: Almost no-one will implement RK4 in 6 dimensions component-wise. Use the system formulation, hints in the links in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4177218/115115

Comment: @LutzLehmann. Thank you for your advice.  My interest is to recheck the results that was obtained using RK4 jn 1980 to understand their methodology and calculations. Please suggest, apart from RK method thag would be the most appropriate or best to solve the equations.

Comment: So essentially your aim is to verify this one RK4 step with reproduction of the intermediate values?

Comment: Yes. Also, the complete equation was broken down into components inorder to see the variations one vs the others and vise versa. Example how does theta changes as r decreses, witn theta how does phi change with time.

Comment: Could you please add the numerical values for all parameters $Ω,B_θ,B_r$ etc.? Perhaps also the equation in Cartesian coordinates and the type of symmetry that makes a solution in polar coordinates preferable?

Comment: $${\Omega =1.4} * 10^{-7} rad/sec$$, $${B_θ = - 8.6 * 10^{-6} cos\theta \quad tesla} $$
, $${B_r = 25893.2 * 10^{-9} sin\theta\quad tesla } $$. The equation is the usual Lorentz force on a moving charge particle due to a spherical magnetic field.  Sir, for your kind information I am new to Nonlinear ODEs and this is my first attempt to solve one. If I can get the values and graph given in the paper it would mean I have learned RK4!. Apart from the approximate method please suggest another numerical method which can be used to verify the same.

Comment: The value of $β=3.12·10^{-18}$ is still missing. The value of $Ω$ is suspect, as in the image in the first value for $f_2$, $Ω^2=0.9·10^{-12}$ is given, so $Ω=9.4868·10^{-7}$.

Comment: In the formulas, $0.5·r_0=0.35·10^8$, giving $r_0=0.7·10^8=7·10^7$. Assuming SI units everywhere, that would be meters, not kilometers. I'm not sure what physical object could correspond to a radius of 70 000 km, or slightly smaller for $R$.

Comment: @Luth Lehmann ,thank you so much for your elaborate explanation.  β  is the q/m ratio of a nano charge particle given in terms of potential. Ω is the angular speed of the spherical magnetic field (say Saturn's magnetic field). The charged particle is assumed to be starting from a distance of r0 =1.18R (Radius of the planet = 60,268,000 m). To say the least, you have been so kind and generous to share your expertise. The equations are adapted from: 1. Consolmagno, G.J. (1983) doi: 10.1029/JA088iA07p05607 and 2.
Schaffer, L. and Burns, J.A. (1987): doi: 10.1029/JA092iA03p02264

Comment: The solutions for the Lorentz equations in a dipole field can indeed look interesting, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3087150/analytic-solution-for-a-3d-dynmaic-system

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann. Yes. That is right. How do you come to know? I, in fact, purposely did not mention that. Only in Saturn's case can the magnetic be considered a perfect dipole.

Comment: From your links it is more about the perturbation of charged particles in the dust rings, not the same as the solar winds caught in the Earths magnet field. Magnetic fields always come at least as dipole, so that trying that first is not a great mystery.

Comment: @ Lutz Lehmann. Thank you once again. You have made the nine months of my struggle meaningful. I wish I can meet you and thank you in person and learn more about non-linear dynamics. I shall continue to work and someday put your name in my publication. Please do continue your noble work of helping others May God bless you and your dear and near one. My regards and appreciation from India, Manipur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right to be suspect of this code, they made a common beginner error, and some others in the course of calculation and transcription.

- The order of the variables is different in the argument tuples and the derivative functions. The arguments are $(t,x,y,z,r,θ,ϕ)$, the functions $(f_1,...,f_6)$ are for $(\dot r,\dot x=\ddot r,\dot θ,\dot y, \dot ϕ,\dot z)$. With $k_j=hf_1, l_j=hf_2,m_j,n_j,p_j,q_j=hf_6$ the first updated point should be $$(t_0+h/2,x_0+l_0/2,y_0+n_j/2,z_0+q_0/2,r_0+k_0/2,θ+m_0/2,ϕ_0+p_0/2).$$ Compare how the arguments that are actually used mix the two argument orders.
- In the formulation used the first equation that is actually solved is $\dot x=f_1(t,..)=x$, giving an exponential function $x(t)=x_0e^t$ as exact solution.
- In $l_0$ the factor $r_0$ is for some reason distributed to the terms in the sum factor, but not to the only non-zero middle term.
- The formula for $n_0$ is sign-incompatible with the formula for $\dot y$, the value is zero anyway.
- In the last 3 or 4 equations of each stage, the updated values are not used?
- There may be some mismatch of degrees and radians?
- On the first page in the last line one finds $p_2=...=0.5·0.06·10^{-12}=0.3·10^{-12}$ which is wrong by a factor of $10$.
- The method used is not RK4, it has 5 stages that are all except the first evaluated at $t+h/2$. RK4 has 4 stages that are evaluated at $t,t+h/2, t+h/2, t+h$.
- The collection formulas for the next point are completely corrupt.

---

In python one can arrange the step computation as

```
from math import sin, cos, pi
Ω=9.49e-7
β=3.12e-18
def acc(u,v):
    r,θ,ϕ = u
    x,y,z = v
    B_θ=-8.6e-6*cos(θ)
    B_r=25893.2e-9*sin(θ)
    ax = r*(y**2 + (z+Ω)**2 * sin(θ)**2 - β*z*sin(θ)*B_θ)
    ay = (-2*x*y-r*(z+Ω)**2*sin(θ)*cos(θ)+β*r*z*sin(θ)*B_r)/r
    az = (-2*x*(z+Ω)*sin(θ)-2*r*y*(z+Ω)*cos(θ)+β*(x*B_θ-r*y*B_r))/(r*sin(θ))
    return np.array([ax,ay,az])

h=0.5
```

1st stage

```
r0,θ0,ϕ0 = 0.7e+8, 0.5*pi, 0
u0, v0 = np.array([r0,θ0,ϕ0]), np.zeros(3)

a0 = acc(u0,v0)
print("acc0 = ",a0)
#>>> acc0 =  [ 6.30420700e-05 -5.51459066e-29 -0.00000000e+00]
```

2nd stage

```
u1 = u0+0.5*h*v0
v1 = v0+0.5*h*a0
print("[r1,θ1,ϕ1] = ",u1)
print("[x1,y1,z1] = ",v1)
#>>> [r1,θ1,ϕ1] =  [7.00000000e+07 1.57079633e+00 0.00000000e+00]
#>>> [x1,y1,z1] =  [ 1.57605175e-05 -1.37864766e-29  0.00000000e+00]

a1 = acc(u1,v1)
print("acc1 = ",a1)
#>>> acc1 =  [ 6.30420700e-05 -5.51459066e-29 -4.27335175e-19]
```

3rd stage

```
u2 = u0+0.5*h*v1
v2 = v0+0.5*h*a1
print("[r2,θ2,ϕ2] = ",u2)
print("[x2,y2,z2] = ",v2)
#>>> [r2,θ2,ϕ2] =  [7.00000000e+07 1.57079633e+00 0.00000000e+00]
#>>> [x2,y2,z2] =  [ 1.57605175e-05 -1.37864766e-29 -1.06833794e-19]

a2 = acc(u2,v2)
print("acc2 = ",a2)
#>>> acc2 =  [ 6.30420700e-05 -5.51459066e-29 -4.27335174e-19]
```

4th stage

```
u3 = u0+h*v2
v3 = v0+h*a2
print("[r3,θ3,ϕ3] = ",u3)
print("[x3,y3,z3] = ",v3)
#>>> [r3,θ3,ϕ3] =  [ 7.00000000e+07  1.57079633e+00 -5.34168968e-20]
#>>> [x3,y3,z3] =  [ 3.15210350e-05 -2.75729533e-29 -2.13667587e-19]

a3 = acc(u3,v3)
print("acc3 = ",a3)
#>>> acc3 =  [ 6.30420700e-05 -5.51459066e-29 -4.27335174e-19]
```

next point

```
unext = u0+h/6*(v0+2*v1+2*v2+v3)
vnext = v0+h/6*(a0+2*a1+2*a2+a3)

print("[rn,θn,ϕn] = ",unext)
print("[xn,yn,zn] = ",vnext)
#>>> [rn,θn,ϕn] =  [ 7.00000000e+07  1.57079633e+00 -3.56112645e-20]
#>>> [xn,yn,zn] =  [ 3.15210350e-05 -2.75729533e-29 -2.13667587e-19]
```

Comment: Sir, the code gives: File ~\.spyder-py3\temp.py:22 in <module>
    u0, v0 = np.array([r0,θ0,ϕ0]), np.zeros(3)

NameError: name 'np' is not defined.   Cannot import numpy in math

Comment: This import is so common I leave it often out. `import numpy as np` and also `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. If you can not import numpy at all, this is a more serious problem.

Comment: Done as your suggestion: import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sin, cos, pi. It now works fine.

Comment: sir, Since none of the terms in the equations contains ''t', it appears that the value of say y1 evaluated at t = 0 seconds or y1 at t= 60 seconds, with RK4.  For example, t0+h/2 or 60 +h/2 does not seem to affect the values of r, x1, y1, z3 etc. If I want to see the values of r,x, theta, y etc at each time ( 1 sec, 2s, 3s, .... 60 s) how would I approach it, or what changes should be made in the codes you have provided?

Comment: You build a function table $(t,y)$. That the equations are autonomous just says that the absolute time or the start time has no importance, but time differences or offsets still retain their importance.

Comment: Sir, that is what I don't understand. Suppose, if the aim is to find the changes of variables between time = 1 sec to 60 s one would not know which value of y's is for which time. how many different values correspond to how much time difference?  If iteration is done 60 times will it mean that the first iteration will correspond to t=1s and the 60th iteration corresponds to t=60s? Also, to match 60 iterations what value of 'h' now be chosen?

Comment: To get the data from 0 to 60 in steps of 1, you repeat doing 2 RK4 steps of step size 0.5. This gives you a function table that you can then plot, or process in other ways. // Assuming that the code in the paper follows the presented write-up, then the numbers from the paper are all useless.

Comment: Sir, once again thank you very much. I have learned so much from you. You make learning mathematics more interesting. To be honest, I was getting irritated with myself for having spent lots of time trying to understand and apply numerical methods in some physical systems. Using RK4 in 2nd ODEs with x/y/z when the derivatives are w.r.t x or y or dz is quite straightforward and lots of solved examples but Higher order ODEs with x/y/z w.r.t time as the above problem was a headache and little solve examples available. It would be of great help if you can write a book/lecture series on this topic.

Comment: Lehman, Sir what is difference between  evaluation of solutions ( u,v, a) with h= (tf - t0)/n = 0.1 ( tf =10, n = 100) and obtaining 4 solution points ( u1...unext)         versus
           evaluation with h= 0.1 for n times with various values for u1.... u1n, .. a1.....a1n) ? I am still very muc confused between tspan iteration and the real time ( actual time of observation of motion)